# Postgres returns []uint8 instead of []integer

Tags: postgresql, go, pq

I'm saving an array of integers into PostgreSQL table, and when trying to retrieve it, I always get []uint8 instead of []int.
I tried to user []integer, []bigint, []smallint. nothing works.
The array represent a maximum of four items, each one between 1-100, no floating point.

I'm using Go, and I have an object that is an []int, this is the field:

```
Quantity []int `json:"quantity" db:"quantity"`
```

I'm trying to fix it but can't find a way to make PostgreSQL to return an []int.

All the other table fields working great. the `Quantity` field is of type `integer[]`

This is the insertion query:

```
"INSERT INTO products (product_id, name, manufacturer, image_url, quantity, amount, notes, store_id, store_name, owner_id) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10)", newProduct.UID, newProduct.Name, newProduct.Manufacturer, newProduct.Image, pq.Array(newProduct.Quantity), newProduct.Amount, newProduct.Notes, newProduct.StoreID, newProduct.StoreName, newProduct.OwnerID);
```

This is how I try and get the data.

```
err := rows.Scan(&temp.ID, &temp.UID, &temp.Name, &temp.Manufacturer,
        &temp.Image, &temp.Amount, &temp.Notes,
        &temp.StoreID, &temp.OwnerID, &temp.StoreName, &temp.Quantity)
```

The problem is only with Quantity.
If I change my `temp object` to `[]uint8` instead of `[]int` I do get the bytes.

Comment: Can you show how you make query to db and what packages do you use for that? Also, show types of table's fields that you're trying to fetch.

Comment: Edited. I'm using "database/sql" and "GitHub.com/lib/pq" packages.

Comment: Are your trying to insert list of int in a column in table ?

Comment: @AbinashGhosh yes, the insert does works, but when Im trying to get the data I get []uint8 instead of []int.

Comment: You've only provided the insert that you claim works. Where's the go code that doesn't work, the code that tries to retrieve the ints?

Comment: @mkopriva Sorry, I added that. the problem is that it does work when I change my object to be []uint8 instead of []int. but I need an array of numbers and not the bytes. Also, can't find a way to cast it on the Scan so I can use it.

Comment: @mkopriva I use it on the insert so I can insert the array into the database, that's the only way it worked for me. I tried using it on the Scan also, but it does not work.

Comment: You need to use `pq.Array` in `Scan` as well. Note that `[]uint8` means a byte slice (`byte` is alias for `uint8`), which means raw data, unparsed postgres array.

Comment: *"I tried using it on the Scan also, but it does not work."* no, it does work. You must've made a mistake somewhere else. Show the code you've tried with `pq.Array` in `Scan`.

Comment: @mkopriva I just wrapped &temp.Quantity with pq.Array.

Comment: @JohnDoah Then somewhere else is the problem, using `pq.Array(&temp.Quantity)` is the correct way to scan postgres arrays into Go slices. What is the error you got when you used that approach? What is the query you've executed to get that row? etc.

Comment: @mkopriva the query is just a select query, nothing special.

Comment: @JohnDoah but that "nothing special" is not working for you and that makes it special, special in a bad way. I mean if you don't want to share the code that's not working as you expect that's fine by me, but you're just making it harder than necessary for us to help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `pq.Array(&temp.Quantity)`

The way you store, you have to retrieve also that way.

```
err := rows.Scan(&temp.ID, &temp.UID, &temp.Name, &temp.Manufacturer,
        &temp.Image, &temp.Amount, &temp.Notes,
        &temp.StoreID, &temp.OwnerID, &temp.StoreName, pq.Array(&temp.Quantity))
```

And you have to use [supported types](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/driver/#Value) for `pq.Array()` also or implement [Scanner](http://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Scanner) interface. For integer you can use `[]sql.NullInt64` or `[]int64`. But it's better to use the same supported type for Scanner and Valuer interface.

Find more details [here](https://godoc.org/github.com/lib/pq#Array).

Comment: Thanks, still trying to get it to work. Is it okay if the column type on the database is integer[]? or should it be something else?

Comment: No. In database it may be byte type because of pq.Array help you to do that

Comment: Here you can see the implementation of Scaner & Valuer interface for int array.
https://github.com/lib/pq/blob/master/array.go#L429
https://github.com/lib/pq/blob/master/array.go#L463

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, but I get this error: pq: parsing array element index 0: pq: scanning to int is not implemented; only sql.Scanner

Comment: Thank you very much! I changed to []int64 as you said and it is working. if I want to change to a smaller int size, do I need to implement the scanner?

Comment: Yes, you need to implement Scanner(https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Scanner) interface for `[]int`.

Comment: Thank you very much!